# Is it possible to have subsection titles and numbers as a header on alternating pages?

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, titleps

I am writing my thesis. I would like have my headers alternating between odd and even pages. Ideally I will have my main section title on even pages and the subsection on odd but I cannot find a way to do this. I have tried using titleps to no avail. I am now using the fancy package.

My attempt using titleps:

```
\newpagestyle{main}{%
    \setheadrule{1pt}%
    \sethead{\thesection~\sectiontitle}       % header left
    {}                                                    % header center
    {\thesubsection~\subsectiontitle\quad}% header right

    \setfoot{}{\thepage}{}
}
\pagestyle{main}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
\newpagestyle{main}{%
   \setheadrule{1pt}%
   \headrule
   \sethead[\thesection~\sectiontitle][][]%headers on even page (left-centre-right)%
   {}{}{\thesubsection~\subsectiontitle\quad}% headers on odd pages
    \setfoot{}{\thepage}{}
}
\pagestyle{main}
```